# Will Barty Crouch Jr.'s power block other villain rewards?

Tags: harry-potter-hogwarts-battle

If a reward from defeating a villain states to remove tokens from the location, does Barty Crouch Jr. block the action?

The effect of Barty Crouch Jr. is `Heroes cannot remove tokens from the Location.`, so does the action come from the defeated villain or come from a hero?

Comment: Can you provide some more details such as the text on the cards for what the powers are?

Comment: Please don't vote to close just because you personally don't have a copy of the game. The question is complete as posed.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson The question should have enough details to not require a google search to understand the basics.

Comment: @JoeW, not every question needs to be able to be answered by someone with no knowledge of the topic.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson That isn't the point, a question should have enough information to be understandable without having extensive knowledge about the subject. And based on the answer the correct name of the card isn't even in the question making it hard for someone to answer since the person answering is making an assumption about what card is being talked about.

Comment: @JoeW that the card name was possibly misspelled didn't come out until later, so is also not the point. And the question is understandable as-is, no knowledge of the game needed.

Comment: I would like to point out that 'Barty Croupton' is the French translation of Barty Crouch, and as such not a misspelling, merely a language-barrier/non-translation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're referring to Barty Crouch Jr villain card.

Unfortunately, the [rulebook](https://tesera.ru/images/items/946760/Harry_Potter_DB_G1_Rules.pdf) doesn't go into the specific use-case when defeating other villains. Luckily, the designers have added some [FAQ clarifications](https://tesera.ru/images/items/946763/Hogwarts_Battle_FAQ_-_2017-02.pdf). In the Boardgamegeek thread: [Barty vs Dementor](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/1643179/article/23812263), a similar question is asked and answered by the designer:

> ... if one has an ability preventing the Heroes from doing something, they do not gain the reward from defeating another Villain. 
>  - [Andrew Wolf (Designer)](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/1643179/article/23812263#23812263)

If Barty Crouch Jr is in play and your team was to defeat a villain whose reward would allow you to remove a token from a location, Barty Crouch Jrs ability may not allow you to.

Villain effects will affect villain rewards.